# wordpress pass bloginfo through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to get the site title through ajax

my php page is,

```
if(isset($_POST['page']))
    {
    $page=$_POST['page'];
    $href = bloginfo('url');
    }
$output = array('siteurl' => $href);
$output = json_encode($output);
echo $output;
```

but it returns empty string, please tell what is wrong with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your ajax script fails because the bloginfo function cannot be used without the wordpress core being loaded. You can include the 'wp-load.php' file for a quick fix but the preferred way is to use the ajax hooks.

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Also `bloginfo('url');` will echo the value, use `get_bloginfo('url');` instead to return the value.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 0):

```
$href = bloginfo('url');
```

should hold a valid url.  If you type "url" into your browser, you won't go anywhere :)

It should look something like

```
$href = bloginfo('http://www.addresstoawebsite.com/');
```

Also, you can't just echo json like that, you'll have to use `var_dump($output);`.

For neat formatting on a `var_dump`:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: $href = bloginfo(); also does not works, should i have i to load any wordpress headers ?

Comment: Look at my example carefully - your code should look like `bloginfo("PUT A WEBSITE ADDRESS HERE");`

Comment: A url is not a vaild parameter for the bloginfo function.